# Nevertheless input different 'data.csv' |Why RNN result's always linear?

Tags: python, matplotlib, keras, recurrent-neural-network, tensor

[image]

It's my forecast code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Dense
import tensorflow as tf

# 난수 시드 설정
np.random.seed(42)
tf.random.set_seed(42)
# Load CSV data
csv_path = 'data.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(csv_path, parse_dates=['Timestamp (KST)'], index_col='Timestamp (KST)')

# Extract relevant columns
data = df['Motion Detected'].values.reshape(-1, 1)

# Normalize data
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
data_normalized = scaler.fit_transform(data)

# Function to create sequences
def create_sequences(data, sequence_length):
    X, y = [], []
    for i in range(len(data) - sequence_length):
        X.append(data[i:(i + sequence_length)])
        y.append(data[i + sequence_length])
    return np.array(X), np.array(y)

# Set sequence length
sequence_length = 24  # Use the past 24 hours for prediction

# Create sequences
X, y = create_sequences(data_normalized, sequence_length)

# Set the percentage for training
train_percentage = 0.8
train_size = int(len(X) * train_percentage)

# Split the data
X_train, X_test = X[:train_size], X[train_size:]
y_train, y_test = y[:train_size], y[train_size:]

# Build the RNN model with LSTM layer
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(50, activation='linear', input_shape=(sequence_length, 1)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')

# Train the model
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=5, validation_split=0.1)

# Predictions on the test set
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)

# Inverse transform the predictions to the original scale
y_pred_original = scaler.inverse_transform(y_pred)

# 예측 결과를 후처리하여 마이너스 값을 0으로 변경
y_pred_original[y_pred_original < 0] = 0

# Plot the results with adjusted x-axis
plt.plot(np.arange(len(y_test)), y_pred_original, label='Predictions', linestyle='--')
plt.title('Motion Detection Prediction (LSTM)')
plt.xlabel('Time (KST)')
plt.ylabel('Motion Detected Count')
plt.legend()

# Adjust x-axis ticks to display every 1 hour
ticks_loc = np.arange(0, len(y_test), 1)
ticks_labels = [time.strftime('%H:%M:%S') for time in df.index[train_size + sequence_length:train_size + sequence_length + len(y_test)]][::len(y_test)//len(ticks_loc)]
plt.xticks(ticks_loc, ticks_labels, rotation=45, ha='right')

# 시작 시간과 종료 시간을 설정하여 시각화 범위를 제한
start_time = '00:00:00'
end_time = '23:00:00'
start_index = ticks_labels.index(start_time)
end_index = ticks_labels.index(end_time)

plt.xlim(start_index, end_index)
plt.xticks(ticks_loc[start_index:end_index+1], ticks_labels[start_index:end_index+1], rotation=45, ha='right')

plt.show()
```

It's my csv example

```
Timestamp (KST),Motion Detected

2023-11-28 00:00:00,0

2023-11-28 01:00:00,0
2023-11-28 02:00:00,0
2023-11-28 03:00:00,0
2023-11-28 04:00:00,0
2023-11-28 05:00:00,0
2023-11-28 06:00:00,0
2023-11-28 07:00:00,0
2023-11-28 08:00:00,0
2023-11-28 09:00:00,16
2023-11-28 10:00:00,27
2023-11-28 11:00:00,23
2023-11-28 12:00:00,70
2023-11-28 13:00:00,60
2023-11-28 14:00:00,38
2023-11-28 15:00:00,11
2023-11-28 16:00:00,36
2023-11-28 17:00:00,2
2023-11-28 18:00:00,14
2023-11-28 19:00:00,37
2023-11-28 20:00:00,53
2023-11-28 21:00:00,45
2023-11-28 22:00:00,59
2023-11-28 23:00:00,28
2023-11-29 00:00:00,0
2023-11-29 01:00:00,0
2023-11-29 02:00:00,0
2023-11-29 03:00:00,0
2023-11-29 04:00:00,0
2023-11-29 05:00:00,0
2023-11-29 06:00:00,0
2023-11-29 07:00:00,0
2023-11-29 08:00:00,0
2023-11-29 09:00:00,13
2023-11-29 10:00:00,49
2023-11-29 11:00:00,15
2023-11-29 12:00:00,1
2023-11-29 13:00:00,19
2023-11-29 14:00:00,36
2023-11-29 15:00:00,64
2023-11-29 16:00:00,0
2023-11-29 17:00:00,28
2023-11-29 18:00:00,21
2023-11-29 19:00:00,37
2023-11-29 20:00:00,7
2023-11-29 21:00:00,17
2023-11-29 22:00:00,7
2023-11-29 23:00:00,21
2023-11-30 00:00:00,0
2023-11-30 01:00:00,0
2023-11-30 02:00:00,0
2023-11-30 03:00:00,0
2023-11-30 04:00:00,0
2023-11-30 05:00:00,0
2023-11-30 06:00:00,0
2023-11-30 07:00:00,0
2023-11-30 08:00:00,0
2023-11-30 09:00:00,3
2023-11-30 10:00:00,13
2023-11-30 11:00:00,29
2023-11-30 12:00:00,22
2023-11-30 13:00:00,51
2023-11-30 14:00:00,16
2023-11-30 15:00:00,27
2023-11-30 16:00:00,36
2023-11-30 17:00:00,62
2023-11-30 18:00:00,22
2023-11-30 19:00:00,61
2023-11-30 20:00:00,34
2023-11-30 21:00:00,19
2023-11-30 22:00:00,59
2023-11-30 23:00:00,12
2023-12-01 00:00:00,0
2023-12-01 01:00:00,0
2023-12-01 02:00:00,0
2023-12-01 03:00:00,0
2023-12-01 04:00:00,0
2023-12-01 05:00:00,0
2023-12-01 06:00:00,0
2023-12-01 07:00:00,0
2023-12-01 08:00:00,0
2023-12-01 09:00:00,31
2023-12-01 10:00:00,9
2023-12-01 11:00:00,27
2023-12-01 12:00:00,22
2023-12-01 13:00:00,57
2023-12-01 14:00:00,61
2023-12-01 15:00:00,38
2023-12-01 16:00:00,48
2023-12-01 17:00:00,15
2023-12-01 18:00:00,18
2023-12-01 19:00:00,7
2023-12-01 20:00:00,33
2023-12-01 21:00:00,30
2023-12-01 22:00:00,23
2023-12-01 23:00:00,67
2023-12-02 00:00:00,0
2023-12-02 01:00:00,0
2023-12-02 02:00:00,0
2023-12-02 03:00:00,0
2023-12-02 04:00:00,0
2023-12-02 05:00:00,0
2023-12-02 06:00:00,0
2023-12-02 07:00:00,0
2023-12-02 08:00:00,0
2023-12-02 09:00:00,17
2023-12-02 10:00:00,52
2023-12-02 11:00:00,30
2023-12-02 12:00:00,53
2023-12-02 13:00:00,35
2023-12-02 14:00:00,36
2023-12-02 15:00:00,28
2023-12-02 16:00:00,43
2023-12-02 17:00:00,52
2023-12-02 18:00:00,64
2023-12-02 19:00:00,42
2023-12-02 20:00:00,48
2023-12-02 21:00:00,26
2023-12-02 22:00:00,54
2023-12-02 23:00:00,20
2023-12-03 00:00:00,0
2023-12-03 01:00:00,0
2023-12-03 02:00:00,0
2023-12-03 03:00:00,0
2023-12-03 04:00:00,0
2023-12-03 05:00:00,0
2023-12-03 06:00:00,0
2023-12-03 07:00:00,0
2023-12-03 08:00:00,0
2023-12-03 09:00:00,51
2023-12-03 10:00:00,29
2023-12-03 11:00:00,8
2023-12-03 12:00:00,14
2023-12-03 13:00:00,19
2023-12-03 14:00:00,67
2023-12-03 15:00:00,35
2023-12-03 16:00:00,9
2023-12-03 17:00:00,40
2023-12-03 18:00:00,52
2023-12-03 19:00:00,8
2023-12-03 20:00:00,9
2023-12-03 21:00:00,53
2023-12-03 22:00:00,38
2023-12-03 23:00:00,2
2023-12-04 00:00:00,0
2023-12-04 01:00:00,0
2023-12-04 02:00:00,0
2023-12-04 03:00:00,0
2023-12-04 04:00:00,0
2023-12-04 05:00:00,0
2023-12-04 06:00:00,0
2023-12-04 07:00:00,0
2023-12-04 08:00:00,0
2023-12-04 09:00:00,8
2023-12-04 10:00:00,62
2023-12-04 11:00:00,42
2023-12-04 12:00:00,33
2023-12-04 13:00:00,9
2023-12-04 14:00:00,13
2023-12-04 15:00:00,26
2023-12-04 16:00:00,35
2023-12-04 17:00:00,39
2023-12-04 18:00:00,62
2023-12-04 19:00:00,22
2023-12-04 20:00:00,58
2023-12-04 21:00:00,14
2023-12-04 22:00:00,7
2023-12-04 23:00:00,7
```

Comment: maybe this is correct result for all your data. Did you tried to plot data together with prediction?

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: Your model is linear, so why expect something not linear?